# Issue with MySqlBulkLoader from C# app

Tags: c#, mysql

I am writing an app to export some data from MSSQL to a MySQL server on a nightly basis. I use a simple query to grab all the data for the previous day and have then tried a few different approaches for getting it to MySQL. The fastest approach is using MySqlBulkLoader but for some reason it isn't moving all the data. After I do the insert, I am comparing the records in the text file that was generated to the number of records that are in MySQL and the counts are off from 1 in some cases all the way up to 10.

If I do the same approach for getting the data to the text file but loop through each row of the text file rather than bulk upload and do insert statements, all the records get imported.

Here is the bulk upload code I am currently using. I recently added the FieldQuotationCharacter to see if that would help and it didn't (when I added that, I made the text generation script enclose fields in quotes).

```
uploader.TableName = "testtable";
uploader.FieldTerminator = "\t";
uploader.LineTerminator = "\r\n";
uploader.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 0;
uploader.FileName = updateFile; //this is a variable pointing to the current file
uploader.Timeout = 120;
uploader.FieldQuotationCharacter = '"';
int totalExported = uploader.Load();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Seems a little strange but on a whim I decided to write my output file with a blank line at the top and then set NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1. After doing this, everything worked and no records went missing. Kinda strange. Seems that setting it to 0 didn't work and may not be supported.

Comment: I have the same experience.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem where it was loading about 2/3 of the rows in my file and the problem turned out to be the behavior of the local keyword in the load data sql that is generated by MySqlBulkLoader.

By default, it seems that MySqlBulkLoader.Local == true, this allows it to use a local file, but also affects the error handling for invalid rows.  Instead of throwing an error when a row is invalid, it will give you "warnings".  You can verify this and view the warning by running an actual sql command for load data (which is what MySqlBulkLoader uses):

```
load data local infile '/Temp/bb7dd81c-c79f-49c7-9ae4-fdc8e48df6d5.csv'
ignore into table my_staging_tbl
fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' escaped by '\\'
lines terminated by '\n'
```

This outputs the count of affected rows and a list of all warnings

In my case, I had the LineTerminator as "\n" instead of "\r\n" and after the warnings were suppressed it still ended up importing most of the rows.

You can override this behavior by setting MySqlBulkLoader.ConflictOption to MySqlBulkLoaderConflictOption.Replace instead of Ignore which is the default.  Note that this also affects the way it handles duplicate keys.

More on the load data stuff for mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 0):

If you stumble upon this post looking for a solution to trap those warnings, here it is. You actually need to add an event handler on the underlying connection to grab them. Like this:

```
connection.InfoMessage += new MySqlInfoMessageEventHandler(OnInfoMessage);
connection.Open();
MySqlBulkLoader bulkLoader = new MySqlBulkLoader(connection);



 void OnInfoMessage(object sender, MySqlInfoMessageEventArgs e) {           
      MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("SHOW WARNINGS", (MySqlConnection)sender);
      MySqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
      while (reader.Read()) {
          Console.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString() + " " + reader[1].ToString() + " " + reader[2].ToString());
      }
  }
```